# Kafka console producer/consumer on minikube ERROR Error when sending message to topic

Tags: apache-kafka, minikube

I am trying to use the kafka console producer and consumer in my minikube cluster.

These are my services:

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
java-api        NodePort    10.108.162.108   <none>        8080:30141/TCP    8d
kafka-service   NodePort    10.104.71.239    <none>        29092:32676/TCP   66m
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP           12d
zookeeper       ClusterIP   10.106.78.82     <none>        2181/TCP          66m
```

My deployments

```
NAME        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
java-api    1/1     1            1           8d
kafka       1/1     1            1           141m
zookeeper   1/1     1            1           141m
```

My pods

```
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
java-api-55ff8cbf8b-xkrcj    1/1     Running   0          8d
kafka-77486f8d89-jhgtk       1/1     Running   0          143m
zookeeper-64b8b5cf6b-bt67h   1/1     Running   0          143m
```

I run `kubectl exec -it kafka-77486f8d89-jhgtk /bin/bash`

When I run:

`kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 10.104.71.239:29092 --topic Kafka_Example --from-beginning`

I get this:

```
WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-60284-1, groupId=console-consumer-60284] Connection to node -1 (/10.104.71.239:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

And

When I run:
`kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.104.71.239:29092 --topic Kafka_Example`

I get this after a while:

```
[2020-09-29 11:46:23,697] ERROR Error when sending message to topic Kafka_Example with key: null, value: 3 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic Kafka_Example not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

The topics exists:

```
I have no name!@kafka-77486f8d89-jhgtk:/bin$ kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper zookeeper:2181
Example_Topic
Kafka_Example
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the

> type: Nodeport

of the kafka-service and now the consumer and producer works within the container.